# How should i be handling string Interning on deserialization?

Tags: c#, string-interning

In the example below I am interning the string in the constructor which is fine. However when i deserialise the object from the binary formatter I don't think the string will be interned as the constructor should be called. How should I be ensuring the _name string is interned? ... or will it be interned ok?

**Edit:** So it seems to work (interns the strings correctly) without handling the OnDeserializedAttribute. How does it do that?

I'm using a memory profiler, with or without the method below it still interns the strings? Magic? :-/

```
   [OnDeserializedAttribute]
   private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
   {
       _name = string.Intern(_name);
   }
```

Thanks

```
[Serializable]
class City
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public City(string t)
    {
        _name = string.Intern(t);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you explicitly Intern string? This is inner mechanism of .net.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you implement the `ISerializable` interface (not the Attribute). It will let you do the deserialization.

But it seems very unnecessary. Are you sure you are accomplishing anything with this?

Comment: That is a micro optimization... you must have a really good reason, like working with a embedded system, to have that as reason for string Interning.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [OnDeserializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx)